# Jquery change from window scroll to load more button

Tags: jquery, scroll, load, infinite

I am working with an infinite scroll script in asp.

1. Does anyone know how to change this jquery to include a "load more" button instead of the code recognising the scroll to end of page?

   ```
   $(document).ready(function(){

       $('form#posts').bind('submit', function(e){
           e.preventDefault();
           checkForm();
       });

       $('input#hostName').focus();


       function lastPostFunc() 
       { 
           $('div#lastPostsLoader').html('<img src="bigLoader.gif">');
           $.post("test.asp?action=getLastPosts2&lastID="+$(".wrdLatest:last").attr("id"),

           function(data){
               if (data != "") {
               $(".wrdLatest:last").after(data);
               }
               $('div#lastPostsLoader').empty();
           });
       };  


       $(window).scroll(function(){
           if  ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){
              lastPostFunc();
           }
       }); 

   });
   ```

Thanks for any pointers in advance.

Richard

Comment: okay, You mean rather detecting whether `scrollTop` reached `windows bottom` you want to load more in advance. Am i right?

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/G65cS/

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
        $('.loadMore').fadeIn(200);
    }
});

$('.loadMore').click(function () {
    $('.loadMore').fadeOut(200);
    $('.container').append(content); 
    // PUT YOUR AJAX REQUEST HERE INSTEAD of the .append();
    /* $.post("test.asp?action=getLastPosts2&lastID="+$(".wrdLatest:last").attr("id"),

       function(data){
           if (data != "") {
              $(".wrdLatest:last").after(data);
           }
           $('div#lastPostsLoader').empty();
       });
    */
});
```

I've used a Lipsum string in the demo for an example, but you could easily replace that with a loading gif and an ajax call for your purposes. Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the `$(window).scroll` event handler and add:

JS:

```
$('#load').click(function() {
    lastPostFunc();
});
```

HTML:

```
<button id="load" type="button">Load more</button>
```

Of course the HTML Button should be added at the end of the page.